# ActiveX Dragging issue in WIN 10/8.1 (C#.NET 4.5.2)

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, windows-10, activexobject

I am having a .NET 4.5 application. We are also providing one Renderer ActiveX control to use in Internet explorer. This ActiveX control has a functionality (on double click) to open the main application for editing purpose.

***Issue:***
We are facing an issue with IE 11 version (only in WIN 10 and WIN 8.1), when we double click on the renderer ActiveX control, the application gets opened but we cannot perform a drag/drop operation in that instance (basically we use drag/drop event to move the drawing with in the drawing area).

***Working Scenarios***

- In all Windows 7 machines with IE 11, this is working.
- All newly created WIN 10 machines, this is working (I have installed all the updates in non-working machines too, but still not working).

Stand alone application working fine always.

I strongly feel that some windows updates make this mess, could anyone please guide me how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Probably a UAC issue, your process gets launched with the same integrity mode as the IE add-in.  Which is lower than a normal desktop.  Google "uipi manifest" for possible workarounds.

Comment: Its not am issue with protected mode, I already tried this. Thanks